# How can I make this LTI CIVIL example code run under Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I tested a program that takes a photo from the webcam and saves it every 2 seconds, based on the LTI CIVIL library. The program worked very well under Windows Vista, but I got an error when I ran it under Ubuntu:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" com.lti.civil.CaptureException:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no civil in java.library.path
    at com.lti.civil.impl.jni.NativeCaptureSystemFactory.createCaptureSystem(NativeCaptureSystemFactory.java:24)
    at emptyroomoperation_final.Camera.main(Camera.java:41)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no civil in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at com.lti.civil.impl.jni.NativeCaptureSystemFactory.createCaptureSystem(NativeCaptureSystemFactory.java:21)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the code:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package emptyroomoperation_final;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.lti.civil.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import com.lti.civil.CaptureException;
import com.lti.civil.CaptureObserver;
import com.lti.civil.CaptureStream;
import com.lti.civil.CaptureSystem;
import com.lti.civil.CaptureSystemFactory;
import com.lti.civil.DefaultCaptureSystemFactorySingleton;
import com.lti.civil.Image;
import com.lti.civil.VideoFormat;
import com.lti.civil.awt.AWTImageConverter;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
*
* @author Ken Larson
*/
public class Camera
{
    static public String s;
    static int w=0;  
    //static File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\mostafa\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects   \\EmptyRoomOperation\\0.jpg") ;
    // static File f2 = new File("C:\\Users\\mostafa\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EmptyRoomOperation\\") ;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CaptureException
    {
        CaptureSystemFactory factory = DefaultCaptureSystemFactorySingleton.instance();
        CaptureSystem system = factory.createCaptureSystem();
        system.init();
        List list = system.getCaptureDeviceInfoList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        {
            CaptureDeviceInfo info = (CaptureDeviceInfo) list.get(i);

            System.out.println("Device ID " + i + ": " + info.getDeviceID());
            System.out.println("Description " + i + ": " + info.getDescription());

            CaptureStream captureStream = system.openCaptureDeviceStream(info.getDeviceID());

            System.out.println("Current format " + videoFormatToString(captureStream.getVideoFormat()));

            captureStream.setObserver(new MyCaptureObserver());
            System.out.println("Available formats:");
            for (VideoFormat format : captureStream.enumVideoFormats())
            {
                System.out.println(" " + videoFormatToString(format));
            }

            final int MAX_FORMATS = 2;
            int count = 0;
            //for (VideoFormat format : captureStream.enumVideoFormats())//not now
            VideoFormat format = captureStream.enumVideoFormats().get(0);//alternative of the above
            int k=0;

            while(k!=10)
            {
                /*if (count > MAX_FORMATS)
                {    System.out.println("Stopping after " + MAX_FORMATS + " formats.");    // could be a lot
                    break;
                }*/
                System.out.println("Choosing format: " + videoFormatToString(format));
                captureStream.setVideoFormat(format);
                s = new String(""+w);
                // File f2 = new File("C:\\Users\\mostafa\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EmptyRoomOperation\\"+s+".jpg") ;

                //  f1.
                System.out.println("Capturing for 2 seconds...");
                captureStream.start();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    return;
                }

                captureStream.stop();
                /*try {
                   // Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Camera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }*/
                //++count;
                w++;
            }
            System.out.println("disposing stream...");
            captureStream.dispose();

        }
        System.out.println("disposing system...");
        system.dispose();
        System.out.println("done.");
    }

    public static String videoFormatToString(VideoFormat f)
    {
        return "Type=" + formatTypeToString(f.getFormatType()) + " Width=" + f.getWidth() + " Height=" + f.getHeight() + " FPS=" + f.getFPS();
    }

    private static String formatTypeToString(int f)
    {
        switch (f)
        {
            case VideoFormat.RGB24:
                return "RGB24";
            case VideoFormat.RGB32:
                return "RGB32";
            default:
                return "" + f + " (unknown)";
        }
    }

}

class MyCaptureObserver implements CaptureObserver
{
    public void onError(CaptureStream sender, CaptureException e)
    {    System.err.println("onError " + sender);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onNewImage(CaptureStream sender, Image image)
    {
        final BufferedImage bimg;
        try
        {
            final VideoFormat format = image.getFormat();
            System.out.println("onNewImage format=" + Camera.videoFormatToString(format) + " length=" + image.getBytes().length);
            bimg = AWTImageConverter.toBufferedImage(image);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {    e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Encode as a JPEG
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Camera.s+".jpg");
            JPEGImageEncoder jpeg = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fos);
            jpeg.encode(bimg);
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is almost the same test code that comes with LTI CIVIL, but with some modifications.

As I understand, LTI CIVIL is supposed to run also under Ubuntu. How can I get this piece of code to run under Ubuntu?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" com.lti.civil.CaptureException:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no civil in java.library.path` is telling you what the problem is. It is not able to find the civil dynamic library. On Ubuntu check LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make sure that the .so file is correctly being picked up.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge in ubuntu is limited. How should I find LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? I searched it and I found nothing

Comment: I am trying to run lti-civil code on ubuntu. I was facing the same issue. To resolve it, I placed the required libcivil.so file at my project root and installed libstdc++.so.5 (sudo apt-get install libstdc++5). I was able to run the code, but I am getting following error:  opened v4l2 device
Found Integrated Webcam card with uvcvideo v4l2 driver
discover_inputs()
Found sources: 1
 0 - Camera 1 (2)
unknown or unsupported format: 1448695129

Comment: seems civil does not support my integrated web-cam. is there a way to add support?

Answer (score 2):

After downloading and looking at the files, it looks like the ones you want are in the lti-civil/native directory. There is linux-amd64 and linux-x86 depending on your version of linux. Now you can do things two ways use LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable which you can set to point to directories where you want linux to search for dynamic libraries.

The other option, which is recommended is to do the following. Create /etc/ld.so.conf.d/civil.conf.  The file should have just one line with the path to where you unzipped or extracted the lti-civil/native/linux-xxx/lib*.so files. You will need root access or sudo access to do this. If you do not have access, then set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the lti-civil/native/.... and it should work.